# How to integrate Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 as Terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cl

I would like to have the Microsoft VS C++ compiler `cl` available in VisualStudio Code.

I have Visual Studio Build Tools installed and can call `cl` from the Developer Command prompt.

The default way [recommended by Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_create-hello-world) to get VS Code to use the `cl` compiler is to call VS Code from the Developer Command prompt.

I would like to do it differently, with a terminal that I can call from VS Code and make it the default terminal if needed.

In Windows Terminal, I get the automatically generated Developer Command prompt entry with the command line:

```sh
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=x64 -host_arch=x64`
```

or

```ps
powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 0d0637f3 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments """-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64"""}"
```

If I paste this line into an existing vscode terminal, it works and I can use the `cl` compiler. But I can't manage to get it into an integrated terminal in `settings.json`.

This is what I tried in the `settings.json`:

```json
"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022": {
    "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\" -arch=x64 -host_arch=x64",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\" -arch=x64 -host_arch=x64"
    ],
    "overrideName": true,
    "args": [],
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
},
```

Since VScode is pretty smart, it recognizes that this won't work and doesn't even list it as an entry within the available terminals.

Furthermore, i have absolutely no idea what to do with the commandline given for PowerShell, notably the three doublequotes after `Import-Module` and how to handle them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following to load VsDevCmd.bat in `cmd.exe` from the VSCode integrated terminal.

For running it through PowerShell, you should be able to just replace the path with `PowerShell`, and alter the arguments to match accordingly (`/k` would become `-NoExit`, etc).

```json
"VsDevCmd (2022)": {
    "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    ],
    "args": [
        "/k",
        // Path below assumes a VS2022 Community install; 
        // update as appropriate if your IDE installation path
        // is different, or if using the standalone build tools
        "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat",
        "-arch=x64",
        "-host_arch=x64"
    ],
    "overrideName": true,
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
},
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct; see my updated answer above to allow for REPL (read-eval-print-loop) interaction.

Comment: Yess-
 thank you
using the "/k" as a seperate Argument from the actual commandline passed to cmd was the trick..
It works!

Comment: I thought by getting an answer for developer cmd, it would be easy to transfer it to the powershell prompt.
Turns out, it isn't.

The Commandline i get from Windows terminal is
`powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 0d0637f3 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments """-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64"""}"`
Again im stuck with the amount of parameters that i don't know how to properly translate into settings.json terminal setup.

Comment: As now i have a working command prompt with access to cl compiler, this isn't urgent in any way, but i feel the solution should be noted here too, as it turns out to be more difficult to accomplish than expected.
So i'm thinking about wheater i should expand this question to cover both, cmd and PowerShell, or having another question?

Comment: first of all, in the Powershell command,  why the heck three doublequotes after `Import-Module` and how  to handle them -all the same, different, escape them, or some of them or whatever???

Comment: @maddes8cht I stumbled across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74714194/9412456) while testing; let me know if it does the trick for you. A couple of your other questions are answered at that link also. Keep in mind, if an arg string contains a quoted path, VSCode will strip the quotes if the path isn't an executable. `"""` is an escape sequence for quotes, but for VSCode you're better off using `'` or `\"`. Inserting a space-escape also works: `"Program^ Files..."`.

Comment: FYI, to see how your args array is being parsed by VSCode, you can set the first arg to `"powershell.exe",`; when it fails, the return code and actual args used will show in your notifications: https://i.imgur.com/67m5jn8.png

Answer (score 2):

Came upon this answer in my search for how to do this. Figured out the powershell version that worked for me and thought I'd share for posterity.

Note: the default profile was my choice but included it in case someone wants to apply the same setting.

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "VSDev_PowerShell",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
   "VSDev_PowerShell": {
      "args": [
        "-noe",
        "-c",
        "&{Import-Module \"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll\"; Enter-VsDevShell 1d058d31 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments \"-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64\"}"
      ],
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
   }
},
```